# How to paginate query results ordered in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, ebean

I'm building the backoffice of my application and I want to get the 20 last users ordered in descending id.

I implemented an infinite scroll in my page, so each time the admin hits the bottom of the page, a new request is sent via Ajax to retrieve the 20 following users, etc, etc... until we get the first user.

To sum up, here are the several queries :

```
select * from users order by id desc limit 0, 20
select * from users order by id desc limit 20, 20
select * from users order by id desc limit 40, 20
...
```

But the problem is that I order users in descending order. So if a new user registers while I'm scrolling, I will have duplicate result each time I send a request.

Let's say my user list is the following and my limit is 3 (instead of 20)

```
1. Pierre
2. Paul
3. Jack
4. Jean
5. Mike
```

- The first query will give me : Mike, Jean, Jack
- The second one : Paul, Pierre

But if a user "Carla" registers between the 2 requests :

- The first query will still give me : Mike, Jean, Jack
- >> Carla registers and get ID 6
- The second one : Jack, Paul, Pierre

The conclusion is that I will have the record "Jack" twice in my table.

This problems looks very ridiculous, but do you know how to avoid this ?

PS : I don't know if you noticed it, but Facebook seems to have a similar problem as when you scroll down your news feed, you can see several times the same item. It must be a more complex problem but the idea is the same.

Comment: Yes I do (with Ebean as ORM), but I kept the problem generic since it's more an algorithmic problem than a database specific.

Comment: As e.g. `LIMIT` is not available in all DBMS, it often is easier you use the tag [tag:mysql] along with [tag:sql] when posting questions. Also the ORM may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to see the newly created user, the solution would be relatively simple.  If ids is a auto sequence - you potentially capture the `max(id)` before running the retrieval queries, and update your query as -

```
select * from users where id <= max_id order by id desc limit 0, 20
```

You may be able to do similar with `time stamp` - if there is a column for `last_created` on the table.

If you somehow want to include the newly created user in your output without repeating results, it would require additional logic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I solved the problem using the max id considering it as a cursor. Each time I fetch a page, I keep the last element id and send it in the next request until its value is 0. That means I fetched all the records. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you basically have two realistic approaches to solving this.  An unrealistic approach is to lock the table while browsing -- then new users can't go in.  Another approach is to create a temporary table for each user when they start the page.  Yuck!

The second is to put a timestamp in when users register.  Then fetch this timestamp and use it for scrolling.  You need to get the timestamp from the database, to avoid slight differences in times on the application side and database side.  Something like:

```
select now() as as_of_date
```

Then put this in a variable and change the query to:

```
select * from users where CreationTime <= @as_of_date order by id desc limit 0, 20;
select * from users order CreationTime <= @as_of_date by id desc limit 20, 20;
select * from users order CreationTime <= @as_of_date by id desc limit 40, 20;
```

Note that in more recent versions of MySQL you can set the current time as a default for a `datetime` time (instead of having to deal with a `timestamp` for this purpose).

Comment: Your answer put me in the right direction, thanks. I ended up using a `maxId` as a cursor. Maybe I'm wrong but `id` is indexed so I think requests are faster than using the creation time of the object.

Comment: Yes they are incremented

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id < PREVIOUS_LIST_LAST_ID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

With each request we can send id, which indicates that up to this id we had shown the result.

But if you want to display newly inserted record also, you can try

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id < PREVIOUS_LIST_MIN_ID OR id > MAX_ID
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

MAX_ID in this case will be value of very first record visible on page